# Can I use the analog pins on an Arduino as digital pins?

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, analog

I need more digital pins on an Arduino. Is it possible that I can use analog pins on the Arduino as digital pins?

Comment: Have you looked at what the data sheet says about these pins and their alternate usage options? If you want to keep it as an analogue input pin then it will work as a digital pin too but, there will be latency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Arduinos based on an Atmega328p (ie most classical Arduinos, like Uno and Nano), you can use analog pins A0 to A5 as digital pins (easiest way is to just write A0 as pin number to use A0 like a normal digital pin). You can also find out the numerical value of A0 and write it instead; or do some math if you want (for example A0+i to access the analog pin #i).

Note however that on the Arduino Nano you have 2 extra analog inputs, A6 and A7, that do NOT map to digital pins (cf [arduino forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/can-nano-rx-a6-a7-be-used-as-digital-outputs/545807/3)). You might still, as suggested by Andy aka, read tha analog value and apply some threshold, which will make them behave as a slow digital input (but you can't use them as output).

For all other Arduinos (there are plenty of boards branded "Arduino" now, you have to look for specics.If you find a detailed pinout, and see a Dxx number for your analog pin, then you can probably use it as digital pin (and you should be able to refer to it via the Dxx name).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you just refer to them as "A0", "A1", etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also refer to analog pins as regular digital pins (14-A0, 15-A1, etc.) but there are exceptions. For example, with the Arduino Giga R1 Wifi <ou cannot use pins A8 - A11 as digital pins, they are only for analog purposes.  Sometimes it is not just analog pins that can be used as digital pins. On the Arduino Giga R1 WiFi (this is speculation from what I have seen in the pinouts,) you can use CANRX and CANTX pins as digital pins.